# Kotlin Regex named groups support

Tags: regex, kotlin, regex-group

Does Kotlin have support for named regex groups?

Named regex group looks like this: `(?<name>...)`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to [this discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/regex-named-groups/1864/2),

> This will be supported in Kotlin 1.1.
>   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12753

[Kotlin 1.1 EAP](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-early-access-preview-updated/1437) is already available to try.

---

```
"""(\w+?)(?<num>\d+)""".toRegex().matchEntire("area51")!!.groups["num"]!!.value
```

You'll have to [use](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html) `kotlin-stdlib-jre8`.

Answer (score 7):

As of Kotlin 1.0 the `Regex` class doesn't provide a way to access matched named groups in `MatchGroupCollection` because the Standard Library can only employ regex api available in JDK6, that doesn't have support for named groups either.

If you target JDK8 you can use `java.util.regex.Pattern` and `java.util.regex.Matcher` classes. The latter provides [`group`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-java.lang.String-) method to get the result of named-capturing group match.

Answer (score 5):

As of Kotlin 1.4, you need to cast result of `groups` to `MatchNamedGroupCollection`:

```
val groups = """(\w+?)(?<num>\d+)""".toRegex().matchEntire("area51")!!.groups as? MatchNamedGroupCollection 
if (groups != null) {
    println(groups.get("num")?.value)
}
```

And as @Vadzim correctly noticed, you must use `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` instead of `kotlin-stdlib`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57158723/992940) is a good explanation about it

Comment: The syntax really sucks, but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin 1.9+, named groups are now available in the common stdlib:

> As of Kotlin 1.8.0, the standard library is compiled with JVM target 1.8. So in 1.9.0, there is now a **common** [groups](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-match-result/groups.html) function that you can use to retrieve a group's contents by its name for a regular expression match. This is useful when you want to access the results of regular expression matches belonging to a particular capture group.

[What's new in Kotlin 1.9.0](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew19.html#new-common-function-to-get-regex-capture-group-by-name) (emphasis original)

They provide a nice example:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val regex = """\b(?<city>[A-Za-z\s]+),\s(?<state>[A-Z]{2}):\s(?<areaCode>[0-9]{3})\b""".toRegex()
    val input = "Coordinates: Austin, TX: 123"

    val match = regex.find(input)!!
    println(match.groups["city"]?.value)
    // Austin
    println(match.groups["state"]?.value)
    // TX
    println(match.groups["areaCode"]?.value)
    // 123
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers did not work for me, what did work however was using the following method:

```kotlin
val pattern = Pattern.compile("""(\w+?)(?<num>\d+)""")
val matcher = pattern.matcher("area51")

while (matcher.find()) {
    val result = matcher.group("num")
}
```

Comment: That seems to be API 16 and above. Any solution for older versions of Android?

Comment: This is pure Java, isn't it? It's not using Kotlin classes

Comment: Yea it uses the package java.util.regex.Pattern

Answer (score 0):

### kotlin

```
fun regex(regex: Regex, input: String, group: String): String {
    return regex
        .matchEntire(input)!!
        .groups[group]!!
        .value
}

@Test
fun regex() {
    // given
    val expected = "s3://asdf/qwer"

    val pattern = "[\\s\\S]*Location\\s+(?<s3>[\\w/:_-]+)[\\s\\S]*"
    val input = """
        ...
        ...
        Location    s3://asdf/qwer
        Serde Library    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde
        InputFormat    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat
        OutputFormat    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat
    """.trimIndent()
    val group = "s3"

    // when
    val actual = CommonUtil.regex(pattern.toRegex(), input, group)

    // then
    assertEquals(expected, actual)
}
```