# How to access a capture group by name?

Tags: regex, kotlin, named-captures

Say I have a [`MatchResult`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-match-result/index.html) `m`:

```
>>> var m = Regex("(?<foo>hello) world").find("hello world")!!
```

How can I access the group named "foo" by name? According to the docs `MatchGroupCollection` implements the [`get(String)` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/get.html), but if I try it I get an exception:

```
>>> m.groups["foo"]
error: type mismatch: inferred type is String but Int was expected
m.groups["foo"]
         ^
```

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088679/kotlin-regex-named-groups-support

Comment: Ah, apparently `get(String)` is only implemented on JVM and JRE8. Given that, does anyone have a suggestion how to easily access a capture group by name without using the `get` operator?

Answer (score 0):

It is the `MatchNamedGroupCollection` that allows getting by name, the `MatchGroupCollection` only allows getting by integer index.

So you need to check the group type before getting the match by name.

Something like: `(m.groups as MatchNamedGroupCollection)["foo"]`

Comment: Hmm, that throws an exception: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Retrieving groups by name is not supported on this platform.`